# Teradata SUBSTRING Index Out of Bounds

Tags: sql, teradata

This query works:

```
SELECT
TOP 100     SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 6 FOR CHARACTER_LENGTH(column_name) - 5) AS X
FROM        db_name.table_name
```

But the following query (with `WHERE` clause added) does not execute.

```
SELECT
TOP 100     SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 6 FOR CHARACTER_LENGTH(column_name) - 5) AS X
FROM        db_name.table_name
WHERE       NOT EXISTS
            (
            SELECT    1
            FROM      db_name2.lookup_name H
            WHERE     H.SRC_NUM1 = X 
                      AND H.SRC_TYPE = 11
            )
```

The query above throws

> SELECT Failed. 2663: SUBSTR: string subscript out of bounds in table_name.column_name

However, this following one works (original `SELECT` is nested)

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (
            SELECT
            TOP 100   SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 6 FOR CHARACTER_LENGTH(column_name) - 5) AS X
            FROM      db_name.table_name
            ) A
WHERE       NOT EXISTS
            (
            SELECT    1
            FROM      db_name2.lookup_name H
            WHERE     H.SRC_NUM1 = X 
                      AND H.SRC_TYPE = 11
            )
```

Why is that so? I am using SQL assistant to execute the queries but I doubt it is of relevance.

Comment: Can't you simply do `SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 6)`?

Comment: Will try that; but the original confusion of why the second query fails remains

Comment: The error is caused by a negative value in FOR. Strange data model, can you show some example data & expected result?

Comment: @xenodevil  because you are using other records (in the first you occasionally don't find any len <6

Comment: This was data from a data mart, where source system occasionally sent length less then 6, even though it wasn't supposed to do that. `TOP 100` was always successful because the erroneous rows were too few (~200 rows in a set of >50 million) and `TOP N` generally returns the same first rows that it encounters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change (maybe error is caused when column_name's lenght is less then 6):

```
SELECT
TOP 100    CASE WHEN CHARACTER_LENGTH(column_name)>5 
            THEN SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 6 FOR CHARACTER_LENGTH(column_name) - 5)  
             ELSE  NULL END AS X
FROM        db_name.table_name
```